# Error MSB4025 when deploying ASP.Net MVC .Net Core app

Tags: git, azure, bitbucket, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code

I am trying to deploy an ASP.Net MVC .Net Core app that was created on an Ubuntu 16.04 system in Visual Studio Code. When attempting to push local git deployment to my Azure app to its Azure App Service.
In the project’s root directory, I ran the following:

```
git push -u azure master
```

and got the following:

> D:\home\site\repository\project.json(1,1): error MSB4025: The project
>   file could not be loaded. Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1,
>   position 1. remote: Failed exitCode=1, command=dotnet publish
>   "project.json" --output "D:\local\Temp\8d436b77fda50dd"
>   --configuration Release remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment. remote:  remote: Error - Changes committed to remote
>   repository but deployment to website failed. To
>   https: //name@myappname.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/mayappname.git  * [new
>   branch]      master -> master Branch master set up to track remote
>   branch master from azure.

I got an almost identical error message when deploying from the identical repo on Bitbucket.

I have found references to this error when dealing with continuous integration paltforms but has anyone else seen this when trying to deploy an ASP.Net MVC .Net Core app? Here is the project.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer":"1.1.*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.2.306",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
     "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "precompile": [ "dotnet bundle" ],
    "prepublish": [ "bower install" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "myNameSpace"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**The solution** was to add a global.json file to the root directory that containes the .net core SDK version:

```
{
  "sdk": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177"
  }
 }
```

Without the global.json file, the Azure Continuous Integration Prroecss will attempt to use MSBuild to build a project.json-based project which will not work.
See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/global.json